# The Upper Bound of the $L^p$ norm of the maximal function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, inequality

Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ Show for the maximal function that

$
||Mf||_{L^p} \leq 2 *5^{n/p}(p/(p-1))^{1/p} ||f||_{L^p}
$

if $1 < p < \infty$ and $||Mf||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_{\infty}$.

I am having a lot of difficulties in solving this problem. I was given a hint that the layer-cake formula was helpful, but I find it challenging to use. also $Mf$ is the maximal function.

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that $Mf$ is in $L^p$ and get a bound of the form $\|Mf\|_{L^p} \leq C\|{f}\|_{L^p}$, with $C$ being the constant you gave. So let's start by looking more naturally first at $\|Mf\|_{L^p}^p$: using layer-cake representation, we have
\begin{align*}
\|Mf\|_{L^p}^p &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |Mf|^p = \int_0^\infty \mu\{|Mf|^p > y\} dy.
\end{align*}
The trick is then a clever change of variables. We're looking at $p$th powers of things, so to get rid of this we make the change of variables $y = t^p$, getting
$$
\|Mf\|_{L^p}^p = \int_0^\infty pt^{p - 1}\mu\{|Mf|^p > t^p\} dt = \int_0^\infty pt^{p - 1}\mu\{|Mf| >  t \} dt.
$$
We then use that $M$ is weak (1,1). However, this isn't enough. We also need to cleverly rewrite $f$ as $f =  f_1 + f_2$, where $f_1 = f$ when $|f|  < t/2$ and $f_2 = f$ when $|f| \geq t/2|$, and use sublinearity of $M$ to conclude a bound of the form (this also uses the weak (1,1) estimate on $M$):
$$
\mu\{Mf > t\} \leq \mu\{ Mf_2 > t/2\} \leq \frac{c\|{f_2}\|_{L^1}}{t/2}.
$$
We can then rewrite this $L^1$ norm of $f_2$ in terms of an integral over a now-smaller region of $f$. After this we again use the layer-cake representation of the integral. Hope this is enough to get started!